# What is the purpose of bivarianceHack in TypeScript types?

Tags: typescript, types

While reading through the TypeScript types for React, I saw a few usages of this pattern involving a `bivarianceHack()` function declaration:

<sub>[@types/react/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L730)</sub>

```
type EventHandler<E extends SyntheticEvent<any>> = { bivarianceHack(event: E): void }["bivarianceHack"];
```

Searching didn't lead me to any documentation on why this particular pattern was used, although I've found [other instances](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/backbone/index.d.ts#L237) of this pattern in use so it seems it's not a React-specific pattern.

Why is this pattern being used rather than `(event: E) => void`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This has to do with function compatibility under the `strictfunctionTypes` option. Under this option if the argument is of a derived type you can't pass it to a function that will pass in a base class argument. For example:

```
class Animal { private x:undefined }
class Dog extends Animal { private d: undefined }

type EventHandler<E extends Animal> = (event: E) => void

let o: EventHandler<Animal> = (o: Dog) => { } // fails under strictFunctionTypes
```

There is however a caveat to strict function type, stated in the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, **except those originating in method or constructor declarations**. Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as `Array<T>`) continue to mostly relate covariantly. The impact of strictly checking methods would be a much bigger breaking change as a large number of generic types would become invariant (even so, we may continue to explore this stricter mode).

*Emphasis added*

So the role of the hack is to allow the bivariant behavior of `EventHandler` even under `strictFunctionTypes`. Since the signature of the event handler will have its source in a method declaration it will not be subject to the stricter function checks.

```
type BivariantEventHandler<E extends Animal> = { bivarianceHack(event: E): void }["bivarianceHack"];
let o2: BivariantEventHandler<Animal> = (o: Dog) => { } // still ok  under strictFunctionTypes
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%20private%20x%3Aundefined%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%20private%20d%3A%20undefined%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20BivariantEventHandler%3CE%20extends%20Animal%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20bivarianceHack(event%3A%20E)%3A%20void%20%7D%5B%22bivarianceHack%22%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20EventHandler%3CE%20extends%20Animal%3E%20%3D%20(event%3A%20E)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20o%3A%20EventHandler%3CAnimal%3E%20%3D%20(o%3A%20Dog)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20fails%20under%20strictFunctionTypes%0D%0Alet%20o2%3A%20BivariantEventHandler%3CAnimal%3E%20%3D%20(o%3A%20Dog)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20still%20ok%20%20under%20strictFunctionTypes%20)

Comment: Cool, so first they enable controversial flags, then they use hacks to avoid following rules dictated by that flags.

Answer (score -1):

As previously mentioned, this is to work around the [--strictFunctionTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) which affects the assignability of a function's type on its parameters.

I thought it was worth demonstrating this further.

## Example

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAegVABAvDEMIHkByAVASgQQGobQSQ1QgAVcMBZAZWljBGGABcBPABwFN4B7AMQDsIAHhQ8uXCOwAejdnwAmAZwgLGAJwCWfAOYA+aBAAUAMzEAuCCLEBKaHoBuXdXIDcDFh24BGfXF59BKhraelIy8kq+-IIA5CZc0RAAPhDRAEYAhqrRegD8EGoArpzmRukANgrsriAgEHUAejlubJy+AEw+fjFxCclpmdkS0rKK3FGBmroQeYXFEKUVVaC1DU0M4DRQEABCeDj4hCgkZFSbEHTNHtvqdpnq6XwAxuwAEumPANZCIgKhI0oGAB0wMyWgU5gezAA2gBdGxQPSQvRbADewDqqRudwezzen0MwMBoPBJEy6QAtuwZKoFMJ+DorOY0FSCqo+CgWnS+DpgABfKFpLEaHGvd4faIwy6ca78b6icR-cLKNSTZE7IX3J6iz6CSL+SxcHQ8pgtdXeLYy-wTYJDMKjS3dMS9FIZLK5fKqIoQErlSrVFYQRpS9UdC3qKKxJ1JF0DELDJUO61TGaeuYLP3LOqBtYMBhAA)

[image]

## Explanation

`'foo' | 'bar'` is a subtype of `string`, or in TypeScript you could say `'foo' | 'bar' extends string`.

When used as parameters to function `F`, the assignability is inverted.

`F<string> extends F<'foo' | 'bar'>` is correct, which shows contravariance on the type parameter.

In the above example, there are two tests each for the function on its own and then with the bivariance hack applied. The first tests for *contravariance* and the second for *covariance*.

Without the hack applied, the function is contravariant only. Whereas after the hack, it's contravariant **and covariant**, so we can say it's **bivariant**.

There's a [really good article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/) about this concept specifically in TypeScript, articulated much better than I'm able to here.