# Typescript type a is not assignable to type b

Tags: typescript, konvajs

## Story

I'm using [konva library](https://github.com/konvajs/konva) with Typescript which is HTML5 Canvas JavaScript framework.

Here is a simple tutorial code that I changed from [javascript](https://github.com/konvajs/konva#quick-look) to typescript.

```
import Konva from "konva";

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const box = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#00D2FF',
  stroke: 'black',
  strockWidth: 4,
  draggable: true
});

layer.add(box);
```

But my Visual Studio Code shows error message like below.

```
Argument of type 'Rect' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Group | Shape<ShapeConfig>'.
  Type 'Rect' is not assignable to type 'Shape<ShapeConfig>'.
    Types of property 'hitFunc' are incompatible.
      Type 'GetSet<(ctx: Context, shape: Rect) => void, Rect>' is not assignable to type 'GetSet<(ctx: Context, shape: Shape<ShapeConfig>) => void, Shape<ShapeConfig>>'.
        Type '(ctx: Context, shape: Rect) => void' is not assignable to type '(ctx: Context, shape: Shape<ShapeConfig>) => void'.
          Types of parameters 'shape' and 'shape' are incompatible.
            Type 'Shape<ShapeConfig>' is missing the following properties from type 'Rect': _sceneFunc, cornerRadiusts(2345)
```

The class `Shape` is in `Shape.d.ts` and `Rect` is in `Rect.d.ts`.
And I can see that `Rect` extended `Shape`! but VSC shows an error.

If I add the two property which is in `Rect.d.ts` to `Shape` class,
**the error is gone**.

```
export declare class Shape<Config extends ShapeConfig = ShapeConfig> extends Node<Config> {
    _sceneFunc(context: any): void; // this was in Rect class
    cornerRadius: GetSet<number, this>; // this was in Rect class
    ...
    ...
```

## Question

I know that `layer.add()` function accept only `Shape` type. But as you know Typescript allows downcasting like below.

```
class Base {
  baseProperty: string = "aaaa";
}
class A extends Base {
  aProperty: number = 1;
}
var a: A = new A();
function test(arg: Base) {
  console.log(arg.baseProperty);
}
test(a); // => No Error
```

I cannot understand why `layer.add()` cannot accept `Rect` type even though it extended `Shape` type.  What did I miss?

I need your advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you try layer.add(<Shape> box) ?

Comment: @CharybdeBE error : `Conversion of type 'Rect' to type 'Shape<ShapeConfig>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions for the library are apparently not tested with `strictFunctionTypes` unfortunately.

If this option is not activated, functions relate bivariantly, but under `strictFunctionTypes` functions relate contravariantly with regard to parameter types. This means:

```
class Animal { private x:undefined }
class Dog extends Animal { private d: undefined }

type EventHandler<E extends Animal> = (event: E) => void

let o: EventHandler<Animal> = (o: Dog) => { } // fails under strictFunctionTyes
```

The error you are getting is on `hitFunc` (and if that is fixed on `sceneFunc`) these are functions that take a second parameter of `this`, in effect `Shape<ShapeConfig>`. And this triggers the error when we try to assign the `hitFunc` in `Rect` that has takes a second parameter, also typed as `this` but in effect `Rect`. You can't assign the function with the derived parameter type to a function signature that would accept any base type argument.

There are multiple possible solution:

1. Use a type assertion

   ```
   layer.add(box as unknown as Shape<ShapeConfig>);
   ```
2. Disable `strictFunctionTypes` (the error goes away with `strictFunctionTypes: false` in tsconfig)
3. Submit a pull request to definitely typed to make `hitFunc` and `sceneFunc` behave bivariantly event under `strictFunctionTypes: true` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667959/what-is-the-purpose-of-bivariancehack-in-typescript-types/52668133#52668133). In this case this would work and preserve the functionality:

   ```
   export type ShapeConfigHanlder<TTarget> = {
       bivarianceHack(ctx: Context, shape: TTarget): void
   }['bivarianceHack']
   export interface Shape extends NodeConfig {
       ...
       hitFunc: GetSet<ShapeConfigHanlder<this>, this>;
       sceneFunc: GetSet<ShapeConfigHanlder<this>, this>;
   }
   ```

Comment: @ByeonginYoon you plan on submitting the PR ? I might do it if you don't