# Why does Typescript allow slicing of types?

Tags: typescript, generics

Can someone explain to me why does this compile in Typescript?

```
class Result<T> {
    object: T | null = null;
}

function setOnlyA(res: Result<{ a: number }>) {
    res.object = { a: 5 };
}

function setAB(res: Result<{ a: number; b: string }>) {
    setOnlyA(res);
    // everything compiles fine, but res object is invalid 
    // at this point according to type definitions
}
```

I would expect `setOnlyA` call to be disallowed in `setAB`. I have `strict` mode on. Do I need some other setting?

Comment: As Titian notes, this was a choice, and it creates type problems, while making some things more convenient. As an interesting note, Swift made the opposite choice, and prevents those problems (while being less convenient), and a very common question is "why doesn't this compile in Swift?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487258/swift-generics-upcasting/30487474#30487474

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fundamental issue with the typescript type system unfortunately. Fields are assumed to be covariant, even though a readable and writable field should actually make the type invariant. (If you want to read about covariance and contravariance, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703116/125734)).

Ryan Cavanaugh explains in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31798):

> This is a fundamental problem with a covariant-by-default type system - the implicit assumption is that writes through supertype aliases are rare, which is true except for the cases where it isn't.

Being very strict about field variance would probably result in a great deal of pain for users, even enabling strict variance for functions was only done for function types and not for methods, as detailed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654):

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those originating in method or construcor declarations. Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as Array)

There are proposals to enable `writeonly` modifiers (and be stricter about `readonly`) or have explicit co/contra-variant annotations, so we might get a strict flag at a later date, but at this time this is a unsoundess/usability tradeoff the TS team has made.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to solve my problem by passing some sort of a result-object setter function - it should be possible to make it complain.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis that is actually simple to do since function parameter types (if you face strictFunctionsEabled) are contravariant: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=51&pln=10&pc=35#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmECuIAuAeAKgPmgbwFgAoaU6AewCMAreYVALmk2gB9oA7FEaAXk+4BuYgF9ixAGZIO9AJbkO0CPFQB5DiACeAQQAUy1AghNdABwZ5oYJlwC2leACdoIgJR9cAN3KyAJu8ISMgMjXUtraABWF1dRcSIpGVR5RQNtACFdR0QmIxQMcJskeydBaEomCFRHWQ4AcxdsAOIyJRV1LT1PD2hsiAA6Klp6PmhPV2EiESA

Answer (score 0):

It's OK because `{ a: number; b: string }` is a subtype of `{ a: number}`. That's how Typescript works: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#14-structural-subtyping

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make sense in this case as Typescript fails to ensure that runtime result matches type definition, i.e. member b is missing on res after a call to setOnlyA.

Answer (score 0):

the system is caring that you implements the type, not that its the exact same type, think about it like an interface -

1. you have to implement its properties.
2. you can add properties to the class that implemented it.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the problem: Typescript fails to ensure typesafety in this case. See the top-voted answer.

Comment: I did... Interfaces only affects type safety on typescript... The example is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

My fixed code looks something like this:

```
class Result<T> {
    private object: T | null = null;

    // this solves the problem
    setObject = (o: T) => {
        this.object = o;
    };

    // this doesn't
    //setObject(o: T) {     
    //  this.object = o;
    //};
}

function setOnlyA(res: Result<{ a: number }>) {
    res.setObject({ a: 5 });
}

function setAB(res: Result<{ a: number; b: string }>) {
    setOnlyA(res);
}
```

i.e. the solution is to use lambda as a setter. Using regular member function doesn't work - the typescript fails to discover the problem just as in the original code.