# Difference between covariant and contravariant positions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, covariance

I'm trying to understand the following examples from the [Typescript advanced types handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types).

Quoting, it says that:

The following example demonstrates how multiple candidates for the same type variable in co-variant positions causes a union type to be inferred:

```
type Foo<T> = T extends { a: infer U, b: infer U } ? U : never;
type T10 = Foo<{ a: string, b: string }>;  // string
type T11 = Foo<{ a: string, b: number }>;  // string | number
```

Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred:

```
type Bar<T> = T extends { a: (x: infer U) => void, b: (x: infer U) => void } ? U : never;
type T20 = Bar<{ a: (x: string) => void, b: (x: string) => void }>;  // string
type T21 = Bar<{ a: (x: string) => void, b: (x: number) => void }>;  // string & number
```

My question is: why are the object properties from the first example considered "co-variant positions" while the second function arguments are considered "contra-variant positions"?

Also the second example seems to resolve to [never](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=62#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUB8UC8UVQgD2AgDsATAZygG8o4AuKACnwYEtiAzCBKAVQEosGAG4B7VqQA0UAEYNmbTtz6DMI8aSgBfKAH4%20UBsQjDuAbgBQoSDgBMABiyxESGvSYso5YAnYBzVXUJaTkPBm9fYgChKDEJbTQzKCgAehSvH38rcGgUWwBGJ3hkN3lPCP9A2I0QsqMAVwBbGW4quM0tROS0jMi-KAAyKGImloQgA) not sure if there's any config required to get it to work.

Comment: That resolves to `string | number` rather than the specified `string & number`

Comment: You're right! Well, I have no idea what I'm talking about. There is a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654#issue-142395780) from a TypeScript engineer that sheds some light on the thoughts behind covariance and contravariance for method signatures, but it's only about methods, so it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for that PR it was super useful. Also I guess the reason for the example not working is [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your observation that one of the examples resolves to `never` is accurate and you are not missing any compiler settings. In newer versions of TS, intersections of primitive types resolve to `never`. If you revert to an [older version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.0.1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUB8UC8UVQgD2AgDsATAZygG8o4AuKACnwYEtiAzCBKAVQEosGAG4B7VqQA0UAEYNmbTtz6DMI8aSgBfKAH4+UBsQjDuAbgBQoSDgBMABiyxESGvSYso5YAnYBzVXUJaTkPBm9fYgChKDEJbTQzKCgAehSvH38rcGgUWwBGJ3hkN3lPCP9A2I0QsqMAVwBbGW4quM0tROS0jMi-KAAyKGImloQgA) you will still see `string & number`. In newer version you can still see the contravariant position behavior if you use object types:

```
type Bar<T> = T extends { a: (x: infer U) => void, b: (x: infer U) => void } ? U : never;
type T21 = Bar<{ a: (x: { h: string }) => void, b: (x: { g: number }) => void }>;  // {h: string; } & { g: number;}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=2&ssc=116&pln=2&pc=101#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUB8UC8UVQgD2AgDsATAZygG8o4AuKACnwYEtiAzCBKAVQEosGAG4B7VqQA0UAEYNmbTtz6DMI8aSgBfKAH4+UBsQjDuAbgBQoSDgBMARiyxESGvSYtqUABYNywBHYAc21VdQlpOQ8GGiCjAFcAWxllLTCoMQltNDMoKAB6fOpfKH9A4iDcnQAyLzioYiSUhDMtIA)

As to why are function parameters contravariant while properties are covariant, it's a tradeoff between type safety and usability.

For function arguments, it is easy to see why they would be contravariant. You can only call a function safely with a subtype of the argument, not a base type.

```
class Animal { eat() { } }
class Dog extends Animal { wof() { } }

type Fn<T> = (p: T) => void
var contraAnimal: Fn<Animal> = a => a.eat();
var contraDog: Fn<Dog> = d => { d.eat(); d.wof() }
contraDog(new Animal()) // error, d.wof would fail 
contraAnimal = contraDog; // so this also fails

contraAnimal(new Dog()) // This is ok
contraDog = contraAnimal; // so this is also ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0De0CmYAuAFAJSbQC+5AUKJDACID2A5jgB57bwAmMCKapAO4MAZsVIUylSngCeAB2zQAYvAA8AFQB80ALzQC8gFzQNJXToBuDRF0qWwAJ2jAG8PI7B9UIE6rXeaDr6YHo6YAB0uIREANz2Ti5uHmCMTH7qacHQXGGkXFH4xLE5EcJiJFKu7p5pBPDYgnBIPsQkAPTtOI6ODI4ANKXl0MIAriC5ImCI6NTJnoHo+tUpaSWd0BAM0HgAFogwaFvQUzMQ0isLLWj1jdB1RB1dGvswB9AMANZzNanMeklfot1l1jnt3u8jtsvtBKEA)

Since `Fn<Animal>` and `Fn<Dog>` are assignable in the opposite direction as two variables of types `Dog` and `Animal` would be, the function parameter position makes `Fn` contravariant in `T`

For properties, the discussion as to why they are covariant is a bit more complicated. The TL/DR is that a field position (ex `{ a: T }`) would make the type actually invariant, but that would make life hard so in TS, by definition a field type position (such as `T` has above) makes the type covariant in that field type( so `{ a: T }` is covariant in `T`). We could demonstrate that for the `a` is read-only case, `{ a: T }` would covariant, and for the `a` is write-only case `{ a: T }` would be contravariant, and both cases together give us invariance, but I'm not sure that is strictly necessary, instead, I leave you with this example of where this covariant by default behavior can lead to correctly typed code having runtime errors:

```
type SomeType<T> = { a: T }

function foo(a: SomeType<{ foo: string }>) {
    a.a = { foo: "" } // no bar here, not needed
}
let b: SomeType<{ foo: string, bar: number }> = {
    a: { foo: "", bar: 1 }
}

foo(b) // valid T is in a covariant position, so SomeType<{ foo: string, bar: number }> is assignable to SomeType<{ foo: string }>
b.a.bar.toExponential() // Runtime error nobody in foo assigned bar
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAbygEMAuKZKAXwCgaAzAVwDsBjYASzmanrjgAUZWIhRp0RPnHIBnYACcOzAObUsASkI0oOkgDpieQr37kARGepQA9NajM4UAEbF5UABYR5EADT24wPYQEAAmoTS0ADYQgU7k8EiokBIm0lByiip+LvLkzIwITl5qRgTausKSplAW2a7kAIzUEXRSAk6atlAAbsSRHCEUUBwywzyGrHC9isTMgWBwMhyc3H4yjgliyVVpGUrKdbn2BUVuVDgjJDJLyszETtFQwBuiSRg7sgr7ajROBno5PTPACiAA8FswIHMOH0BJ07AAlFicJBQLzyOBuBxOOAhEBjVJXG6QwY5GhAA)

You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696173/strictfunctiontypes-restricts-generic-type/61703116#61703116) post of mine on variance in TS interesting.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! It did seem absurd to me how properties are covariant but I your point "would make life hard so in TS" answers that dilemma for me

Comment: This can be helpful to anyone who doesn't understand "variance" in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: Also this talk on varianace https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EInunOVRsUU