# For a React + TypeScript variable: enforce some attributes in the "props" of a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to have a variable (actually function argument, but I simplified the problem) that can hold a React component that MUST have e.g. `aNumber: number` among it's properties.

My unsuccesfull try was:

```ts
function MyComp(props: { aNumber: number, aString: string }) {
    return <>{props.aNumber} {props.aString}</>;
}

let f2: FunctionComponent<{ aNumber: number }> = MyComp;
```

giving me the error:

```
Type '(props: { aNumber: number; aString: string; }) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{ aNumber: number; }>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Property 'aString' is missing in type 'PropsWithChildren<{ aNumber: number; }>' but required in type '{ aNumber: number; aString: string; }'.ts(2322)
```

`FunctionComponent` is defined in react as:

```ts
    interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }
```

I don't understand the error. If I defined a var w/ a constraint to have `aNumber`, and I assigned to it a richer element => why isn't it happy? And why it complains about those "richer" attributes?

Of course, the following works:

```ts
let f1: FunctionComponent<any> = MyComp;
```

Usually when I try advanced typing constructs in TS, I finally get it working, after a lot of head aches. This time it doesn't seem advanced, but I didn't manage to figure it out.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Define the function like this:  `function MyComp(props: { aNumber: number, aString: string | undefined }) {return <>{props.aNumber} {props.aString}</>;}`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that React components are functions and functions are *contra*variant, meaning that if a function with parameters of type `T` is required then it can be satisfied with a function of a wider type than `T` but not a narrower type.  That is as opposed to, say, plain objects, which are *co*variant, i.e., that will accept a narrower type, but not a wider one.

You can see the same thing without any React code

```
function MyFunc(props:{a: number, b: string}){return}

let func2: (props:{a:number})=>void = MyFunc 
//   ^-- error because MyFunc is narrower than typeof func2
```

An intuitive way to think of this is from the perspective of the consumer calling your function/React component.  In the case where they are expecting to call a function of `typeof f2`, they are expecting to only need to pass it props of `aNumber` and yet by assigning a narrower function to f2, they would now need to also pass `aString`, which they were not expecting.

This issue comes up a lot in React for an understandable reason.  Imagine you have a `<Button>` component, that takes one prop, and a `<FancyButton>` component that takes multiple props.  It's tempting to think, well, if I need any old `<Button>` than a `<FancyButton>` will do just as well.  That sort of sounds like simple inheritance.  But if you think about it a little more, there's an error.  If I'm a *component* expecting to need to insert a `<Button>` as one of my children, that means I'm only expecting to need to pass it *one* prop.  If I now swap in a `<FancyButton>` a bunch of props are now expected by that component that I wasn't expecting to provide.

The intuitive point is that you aren't just *displaying* the `<Button>` component--in which case you could just not care about the fact that the `<FancyButton>` has more "fanciness".  It's that you actually need to *provide* inputs--props--to the component, and so a narrower one will require you (the parent component) to provide more.

The same logic is of course generally true for all functions, but I guess it tends to come up more often in React because we tend to think of components as "objects to display".

Here is a more expansive SO answer on this issue generally (which is tricky at first!):  [Difference between covariant and contravariant positions in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496072/difference-between-covariant-and-contravariant-positions-in-typescript)

Comment: Please see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) . I'm constantly updating this question with useful links and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883765/no-error-when-generic-types-doesnt-match-in-typescript/69884505#69884505) with some simple examples

Comment: @captain-yossarian, good link.  i added a little more in the answer about why (I think) this comes up in React and how to think about it intuitively.  I'm not sure what the SO policy is on paywall links so not adding to the answer itself.

Comment: It requires a subscription (though you can watch one for free, I think), but I've found this explanation (from Swift programmers) very helpful.  https://www.pointfree.co/episodes/ep14-contravariance

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, comments, links. I've read them twice and ... it's really sort of mind breaker. My conclusion would be that trying to mimic the classic OOP practice where I expect `<Button/>` and I receive `<FancyButton/>` is not actually doable.

Comment: And after reading the 3rd time, I finally explained myself @sam256s example the following way: 1) MyFunc needs both a and b. 2) if the assignment to f2 would be succesfull, AND I'd give this f2 to someone, he would say: oh, so I got a function, which needs a. 3) but this is false; the function really needs both a and b, which f2 now hides

Comment: That’s exactly it. It’s a bit of a mind bender at first but now you have an intuition for contravariance!

Comment: However, I'm wondering if maybe I don't look in the right direction. Actually I have a function argument of type component. And I want to force the caller to pass a component which has at least "aNumber: number" for its "Props". I saw some "type magics" that seemed to have types meant just for validation, not for actual use.

Comment: I’d suggest asking a new question with a minimum reproducible example of what you are trying to do. Verifying that a component has at least X props is doable but depends a little on your context.

Comment: Thanks. Just done that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214702/passing-a-react-component-as-arg-to-a-typescript-function-impose-a-minimal-shap).