# Passing a React component as arg to a TypeScript function: impose a minimal shape of the "props" of the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a TypeScript function with the signature:

```ts
function connectRRC<C extends ComponentType<any>>(component: C)
```

which currently accepts any component.

I'd like to accept ONLY components that have in "props" a given property. E.g. "id: string".

Doing:

```ts
function connectRRC<C extends ComponentType<{ id: string }>>(component: C)
```

doesn't work, cf. [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183835/for-a-react-typescript-variable-enforce-some-attributes-in-the-props-of-a-c).

`ComponentType` is defined in React like:

```ts
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | FunctionComponent<P>;

interface ComponentClass<P = {}, S = ComponentState> extends StaticLifecycle<P, S> {
    new (props: P, context?: any): Component<P, S>;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextType?: Context<any>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    childContextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any hints!

### Update

@sam256 provided a partial working answer, which I found acceptable. However, I found additional use cases that don't work, w/o finding a reasonable explanation. This [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wCgYBPMJRJARwFdgiATABRzAGc4BeOAN7AWALi4wowAHYBzAL6lSmBlIzAIUuGg1SkGBAgDCAHgAqcJAA8YSKSx7JGzJO05cAfAApt4DbZgitOgwAHSGuJC6UjCmVEhm7gCUAgqk2lLicDIQECzhvlHw-J5gbiJCouKSsgA0cBAwABZIUBwQYCJSDCAARi1yiXzucMYswABucAD07mkamT0oeRF+0XxwJWUCDc2tnJ3dfVADQyNjkzOK6br6Rp7ZufmR-olzUjcwBoaei8sFL9MppRqFw0JIwPAWjgoIoplM4AAhBihEKoq7zeBSCBtbhPVZFDaldpccoDXjuUYTaaza56T53LE4rh4wqDOFwLEWKDQuB9NAoBhcGjmYA8aRwJo0dISFDjFCSFBrSBcYAwdSacXIYIhABiJlMszSABsUFweABxHJ-Z7RABMFmstnsQQwYRWhWMFTEEmkMjqOxaOIOvX6cAAZII4FxcEgmr6AKJGoWBHo5I2oTRyYYpN4fL6eS2Pd3+W2vY2mngIpYs-wAZmMbHWAijMbjskTyd5aYzcCzDpsdgcxFCNeinuE3uqfvqkr27WDRzk4bgbGzClpt2+Vet+NrZbQJrNiOrxeiABYG02+1YB86ta7RzBx5UfbUZ7sg10Q8dl6vBOudDpfNt0fM9XiAA) shows them.

This works, as expected:

```ts
class GoodComponent2 extends React.Component<{id:string, otherProp:number} & { somethingElse: boolean }> {}
connectRRC(GoodComponent2)
```

But the following don't work:

```ts
class BadComponent3<P = { somethingElse: boolean }> extends React.Component<{id:string, otherProp:number} & P> {}
connectRRC(BadComponent3)

class BadComponent4<P = {}> extends React.Component<{id:string, otherProp:number} & P> {}
connectRRC(BadComponent4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer.

```js
type RequiredProps = {id:string}

function connectRRC<T extends RequiredProps>(component: React.FC<T>){}

const goodComponent = (props:{id:string, otherProp:number}) => <div />
const badComponent = (props:{otherProp:number}) => <div />

connectRRC(goodComponent)
connectRRC(badComponent) //typescript error
```

This works pretty much as you want because Typescript is now inferring `T` and making sure it extends `RequiredProps`.

The only problem is this won't generate an error for a component passed with no props at all.  This doesn't generate an error:

```js
const noPropsComponent = (props:{})=><div />
connectRRC(noPropsComponent)
```

The reason is contravariance again, at least in part, though I don't completely understand what the compiler is doing here.

What appears to be happening is TS does **not** infer `T` as `{}` and therefore failing to satisfy the constraint (can anyone explain why not?)

Instead, it looks like it assumes `T` is at least `RequiredProps` (the constraint) and then just checks if `component` satisfies `React.FC<RequiredProps>`, which it does because `RequiredProps` is in the *contra*variant position.

I'm not sure of a good way to get past this, in part because I'm not sure I totally get why TS is behaving this way.  Specifically, I don't understand why it doesn't infer `T` as `{}` and fail it for not satisfying the `RequiredProps` constraint.

Hopefully someone else on the forum can help...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wCgYBPMJRJARwFdgiATABRzAGc4BeOAN7AWALi4wowAHYBzAL6lSmBlIzAIUuGg1SkGBAgDCAHgAqcJAA8YSKSx7JGzJO05cAfAApt4DbZgitOgwAHQAYiam7gCUAgqk2lLicDIQECyGuJC6UvD8nmBuIkKi4pKyADRwEDAAFkhQHBBgIlIMIABGDXLRfO5wxizAAG5wAPTuCRrJHSgZWX65fHAFRQI19Y2cre1dUD19A0OjE4qJuvpGnqnpmb45MNFTUhcwBoaes-P3-r1jY5RqFw0JIwPAGjgoIp-nAAEIMUIhJFnabwKQQJrcO7ZfzLVbNLjFHq8dyDEbjSbnPRvK7ozFcbGLR7jMZwdEWKCQuBdNAoBhcGjmYA8aRwOo0RISFDDFCSFBLSBcYAwdSaUXIYLhSLuIA)

Comment: Thanks for the construct. It worked until I found another use case that doesn't work and I cannot explain. This works, as expected: `class GoodComponent2 extends React.Component<{id:string, otherProp:number} & { somethingElse: boolean }> {}`. But the following don't work: `class BadComponent3<P = { somethingElse: boolean }> extends React.Component<{id:string, otherProp:number} & P> {}` or `class BadComponent4<P = {}> extends React.Component<{id:string, otherProp:number} & P> {}`. I updated my question w/ link towards TS playground, because the link is too long for a comment.