# Inferences from JSX vs calling React Components as functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having a little trouble understanding how Typescript infers props in JSX.  The issues has come up in the following context -- I'm trying to make a component that accepts another component as a prop, e.g. (a simplified example):

```js
function WrapperComponent<T extends FooComponentType>(
    {FooComponent}:{FooComponent:T}
){
  return FooComponent({className:"my-added-class"})
}
```

Where `FooComponentType` is the type of a component that has a `className` prop:

```js
type FooComponentType = (props:{className:string}) => JSX.Element
```

What I'd like, is for Typescript to disallow any attempt to pass in a component that doesn't have a `className` prop.  Now, I recognize the typing above will not achieve that because React components are functions and so [the props argument is covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183835/for-a-react-typescript-variable-enforce-some-attributes-in-the-props-of-a-c), i.e., a type that would be satisfied by a component with a `className` prop will also be satisfied by a component without one.  Therefore, both of these components legitimately extend `FooComponentType`

```js
const ComponentNoClass = ()=><div/>
const ComponentWClass = (props:{className:string})=><div/>
```

A workaround that I'm familiar with is to use a conditional time to essentially force the type to be bivariant by having some other type resolve to `never` if the passed component doesn't exactly match (i.e., if both types don't extend each other).  My thought here was I could use such a type to make the return type of `WrappedComponent` be `never` if the passed component didn't have the `className` prop.  So, to that end, I wrote the following helper type:

```js
type JsxIfHasClassNameProps<
  T extends FooComponentType
> = FooComponentType extends T ? JSX.Element : never
```

And used it to create a "smarter" version of `WrappedComponent`:

```js
function CheckedWrapperComponent<T extends FooComponentType>(
    {FooComponent}:{FooComponent:T}
):JsxIfHasClassNameProps<T>
{
  return FooComponent({className:"my-added-class"}) as JsxIfHasClassNameProps<T>
}
```

I would think that would work, but it doesn't.  Sort of... It doesn't work if I call `CheckedWrapperComponent` using JSX, but it does work if I call it as a normal function with arguments, namely:

```js
// this type is JSX.Element as expected
const cjsx1 = <CheckedWrapperComponent FooComponent={ComponentWClass} />
// this type is also JSX.Element, but I want it to be never
const cjsx2 = <CheckedWrapperComponent FooComponent={ComponentNoClass} />
// this type is never as expected and desired
const cjsx3 = CheckedWrapperComponent({FooComponent:ComponentNoClass})
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can get the behavior I want?

Here is a [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-ts-inference-example-gbqs7y?file=/src/App.tsx:237-331).

(BTW, I don't think this changes anything, but I had to call `FooComponent` as a function inside `WrapperComponent` to get around an error TS was giving me regarding the Intrinsic attributes it applies to JSX.  I'm open to a better way to do that, but it's not a huge priority as that implementation is all hidden from the consumer.  By contrast I can't reasonable expect consumers not to call `CheckedWrapperComponent` using JSX)

### Edit

Just to clarify, my question is not about how to solve the contravariance issue generally.  It's more specifically about how to solve it a way that is compatible with JSX.  As noted in the second and third examples above:

```js
// this type is also JSX.Element, but I want it to be never
const cjsx2 = <CheckedWrapperComponent FooComponent={ComponentNoClass} />
// this type is never as expected and desired
const cjsx3 = CheckedWrapperComponent({FooComponent:ComponentNoClass})
```

I can solve the issue if I pass in the component as a "normal" function argument.  My question is why that stops working when I pass it in to JSX as a prop--and can this be achieved?

(Also, as noted in the comments, calling a functional component directly as is done in my examples is not the recommended way to do a non-JSX call, but I don't think that's relevant to my question which is really about TS.  The same behavior occurs if you, properly, use `React.createElement`)

Comment: The note at the end of the question is likely related to the issue, but it sure is the wrong way to use a component. If the component is a class component, it should still work, but your wrapper assume it always receives a function component.

Comment: I could be missing something but I don't see how the code inside the function could be causing this given that the return type of the function is asserted.  In terms of calling a function without JSX, the typing is already assuring that only functional components can be passed--in our projects we don't use class components.  Is there some other reason this is the wrong way to call a component?  I was under the impression JSX was just sugar on a function call.

Comment: [If you want to avoid JSX, you need to use `React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html), otherwise, it doesn't create an instance of the component, it could lead to all sorts of problems in the child component (rules of hooks, lifecycle, debugging the tree, etc)

Comment: I tried to find a way quickly, and looked at `React.ComponentType` but couldn't come up with something that rejects components without a `className` prop.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, thanks.  I admit that I hadn't appreciated that `createElement` was still needed with functional components.  However, the problem persists if I change the call to `React.createElement(FooComponent, {className:"some-class-name"})`, so I believe the Typescript issue is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this out](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-ts-inference-example-forked-xx3gpg?file=/src/App.tsx):

[image]

```js
type FooComponentType = (props: { className: string }) => JSX.Element;

function wrapComponent<C extends FooComponentType extends C ? any : never>(
  Wrapped: C
) {
  return React.createElement(Wrapped, { className: "my-added-class" });
}

function ComponentNoClass(props: {}) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div onClick={() => setState((x) => x + 1)}>
      my classname is... oops I don't have a classname. [{state}]
    </div>
  );
}
function ComponentWClass(props: { className: string }) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div onClick={() => setState((x) => x + 1)}>
      my classname is {props.className}. [{state}]
    </div>
  );
}
function ComponentWClassPlus(props: { className: string; foo: number }) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div onClick={() => setState((x) => x + 1)}>
      my classname is {props.className}. [{state}]
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  const jsx1 = wrapComponent(ComponentNoClass); // not fine
  const jsx2 = wrapComponent(ComponentWClass); // fine
  const jsx3 = wrapComponent(ComponentWClassPlus); // fine

  return (
    <div>
      {jsx1}
      {jsx2}
      {jsx3}
      <button onClick={() => setState((x) => x + 1)}>
        increment outer count. [{state}]
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**What's going on here?**

`wrapComponent()` is basically a ["higher order component"](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) function, that returns some rendered JSX from some component function/class that you call it with.

```
return React.createElement(Wrapped, { className: "my-added-class" });
```

The special sauce that gives you the type checking you crave is this: `C extends FooComponentType extends C ? any : never`.

It essentially says, "generic type `C` extends the conditional type (does `FooComponentType` extend the generic type `C`? If so, this type is `any`, otherwise it is `never`)".

It's a sort of counterintuitive way to get around the covariant issue you mentioned earlier, using a conditional type + `never` to assert the type. It *feels* circular somehow (`C extends FooComponentType extends C`???) but I guess because of the way TypeScript evaluates the conditional type from the inside out, it's fine?

You were pretty close with your implementation of `CheckedWrapperComponent`, but this way you cut out that middle man and only need to use the higher order component function.

Comment: I definitely appreciate this answer and like the idea of the conditional constraint to get around the covariant issue.  However, my question is really about why there isn't some way to achieve this with a wrapper component than can be called via JSX.  Your solution, like mine, ultimately still involves passing the wrapped component into a "normal" function rather than as props in JSX. I'll try to clarify that a little more in the question; sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: @sam256 it [works the same](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-ts-inference-example-forked-0wn9kn?file=/src/App.tsx) if used as a component with JSX.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, thank you for pointing that out!  i still don't understand why my solution did not work, but I'm happy to have this workaround!