# typescript generics: Parameters<URLS[T]> and URLS[T] do not match

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```js
const urls = {
    inviteNewUser: ({teamId, intent = 'invite'}: {teamId: string; intent?: Intent}) => `/magic-link?intent=${intent}&teamId=${teamId}`,
    resetPassword: ({intent = 'reset-password'}: {intent?: Intent}) => `/magic-link?intent=${intent}`,
} as const

type URLS = typeof urls
type OptionArgs<T extends keyof URLS> = Parameters<URLS[T]>[0]

export function getUrl<T extends keyof URLS>(
    key: T,
    options: {
        args: OptionArgs<T>
    } = {
    args: {}
  },
) {
    const urlCreator: URLS[T] = urls[key]

    const args = options.args // <- this should be strictly typed according to the key passed in
    const url = urlCreator(args) // <- but here I get the error `Property 'teamId' is missing in type '{....`

    return url
}
```

Which throws the following type error:

```
Argument of type '{ teamId: string; intent?: Intent | undefined; } | { intent?: Intent | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ teamId: string; intent?: Intent | undefined; }'.
  Property 'teamId' is missing in type '{ intent?: Intent | undefined; }' but required in type '{ teamId: string; intent?: Intent | undefined; }'
```

I don't understand why this error happens. To my understanding, it should be clear that `URLS[T]` and `Parameters<URLS[T]>[0]` should always match. What is the reason that doesn't work, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is an issue with correlated unions as described at [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended refactoring is described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If I follow that I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wX171N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz in some ways, but now the function call isn't strictly typed anymore: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nry5Dw), so I can just call `getUrl('inviteNewUser')` without any parameters even though they should be required here. Will work my way through that github thread and see if I can find another approach

Comment: You say "now" the function call isn't strictly typed "anymore", but I didn't change how the function could be called: [see playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2va8w). I don't know what you want to do there or why it's relevant to the question.  Can I proceed with my answer or do you want to [edit] the question so that the issue you're talking about isn't present?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `urlCreator` in your function body with this -

```ts
const urlCreator: URLS[T] = urls[key];
```

You're creating a union of both the function types, and for any kind of union, typescript does type narrowing, for instance -

```ts
type Test = string | "something";
//   ^? type Test = string;
type Test1 = number | 199;
//   ^? type Test1 = number;
```

Similary, when you create the `urlCreator`, typescript does narrowing on it, to determine if there's one type that would encompass both, and when it does, what it finds is -

```ts
const url = urlCreator(args) // <- but here I get the error `Property 'teamId' is missing in type '{....`
    //          ^? const urlCreator: ({ teamId, intent }: { teamId: string; intent?: any;
}) => string
```

Why does that happen? Whenever the type narrowing happens, and also, generally, the parameters of a function are [contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496072/difference-between-covariant-and-contravariant-positions-in-typescript) and so an intersection is taken, a way to see this is to convert one of your parameters to an array, let's see it -

```ts
const urls = {
    inviteNewUser: ([{teamId, intent = 'invite'}]: [{teamId: string; intent?: Intent}]) => `/magic-link?intent=${intent}&teamId=${teamId}`,
    resetPassword: ({intent = 'reset-password'}: {intent?: Intent}) => `/magic-link?intent=${intent}`,
} as const

.... // Other content

    const url = urlCreator(args) // <- but here I get the error `Property 'teamId' is missing in type '{....`
    //          ^?const urlCreator: (__0: [{ teamId: string: intent?: any; }] & { intent?: any; }) => string
```

See? An intersection. The type of `arg`? That's a union of both the types instead of an intersection, i.e., -

```ts
const url = urlCreator(args) // <- but here I get the error `Property 'teamId' is missing in type '{....`
    //                 ^?const args: { teamId: string; Intent?: any } | { Intent?: any }
```

Which is why typescript complains with -

> Argument of type '{ teamId: string; intent?: any; } | { intent?: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ teamId: string; intent?: any; }'.
> Property 'teamId' is missing in type '{ intent?: any; }' but required in type '{ teamId: string; intent?: any; }'.(2345)

Simplest way to solve this, if you don't wish to change your approach is just adding an as assertion for `key` parameter and removing the explicit typing of `urlCreator` i.e.,

```ts
const urlCreator = urls[key as "resetPassword"]
```

This resolves issue because the `key` here, instead of being of type `"resetPassword" | "inviteNewUser"` is explicitly asserted to be `resetPassword` due to which the type of `urlCreator` is of type `({ intent }: { intent?: any; }) => string` and it accepts the `arg` parameter.

Otherwise, you may want to consider doing a major refactoring of types and maybe even function as well.