# Type of an Array of interface depending of T

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an Interface that has a function depending of T which can extends form a string or a number.

```
interface IConstructorReg<T extends string | number> {
    constructor: new (...args: any[]) => BaseImportObj;
    check: (data: T, fileName: string) => boolean;
}
```

I want to push objects that implements that interface.

```
function checkFun1(data: string, fileName: string) {
    // Severals Checkers ...
    return true;
}
const objImp1: IConstructorReg<string> = { constructor: ASCReader, check: checkFun1 };

function checkFun2(data: number, fileName: string) {
    // Severals Checkers ...
    return true;
}
const objImp2: IConstructorReg<number> = { constructor: ASCReader, check: checkFun2 };

const b: Array<IConstructorReg<string | number>> = [];
b.push(objImp1); //  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
b.push(objImp2); //  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

. Which is the correct type of the Array "b"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it's core this is an issue of variance, namely the variance of `IConstructorReg`. Since `T` appears as the parameter in a function signature, `IConstructorReg` is contravariant in `T`. This means that `IConstructorReg<string | number>` is not a base type for `IConstructorReg<string>`, but rather the other way around (the contra in contravariant comes from the arrow of inheritance pointing in the opposite direction as for `T`, you can read more about variance in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703116/125734) answer)

To get this to work, you can do one of two this.

You can change `Array<IConstructorReg<string | number>>` to `Array<IConstructorReg<string>  | IConstructorReg<number>>` this will mean that the array can contain either `IConstructorReg<number>` or a `IConstructorReg<string>`. But when you use items from the array you need to check which one of the two it is in order to be able to call `check`, and at the moment your interface does not have a way to preform this check at runtime:

```
const b: Array<IConstructorReg<string> | IConstructorReg<number>> = [];
b.push(objImp1); 
b.push(objImp2); 
b[0].check(0, "") // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
(b[0] as IConstructorReg<number>).check(0, "") // type assertion is an option
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCSBbADgewE4BcDyARgFbQDeAvgFCiQwCCAygMIBKCYAJglmVZQJYA7HNwBmYYAmhImGQRBxYArsBzY2AcwA8AFWgIAHiMEcYCrEI3QAPtEFKUBbgD4ylaB+jA55lWqwAXHYIAO7QABQAdNFgWBoQQWCCAJ4A2gC6AJTQALyu8BDI6Nj4xADc7p7AABYIwADWQeEcYDhgQToANNCi-CAIAHJgKAhB5pbZedAEGBj9SRV8lKJKgqr8cl61DQBiqwCMza3t0OOCGt29-UMjY4oTbp7QAPTP0AwIAG7cYCAwTNt6twYNFIpUPFgEDglFhBNBFEoEItqD4cNAMMRUGh9kEZKjlKp1AhtGcNK4cmQvPi-NggoxWOwuFhujU6o0tmy9oJ9tByBVlqt1ptWbtVgAmI5tIL2RzcS59QbDUane7nbKkcEvN4fb5YX7-QHA6CgzWQ6Gw+HKJGUKjeeRojFELFi3Gye0E-yaLQypxYcmUu2+QmBaD0ticOUchpBEX1Lli3n8wNogh0rB65JaPHumlYL2kmx2By+5z+jIVAiRNBKCDVcKOrH7TJlaCUSvV2v1zHoMXN1sEVIABnSkVj4UH3QARJO+69Q3EHAhhOjRPDkmgpAByH3cTfQfgwQQYNG0fgaQRgAj9eEYaBoWJKkQ8DCrnDrreCL67sHhAfD6CQNIbpBp6xLesWLiZKOgLjlOM5amuG4AVA3A4BscIHgBcIYGgaGbEAA)

The other solution is to use method syntax instead of function field syntax to define `check`. This will make `IConstructorReg` bivariant in `T`. While this will not require a type assertion or a check, it is inherently type unsafe as either `string` or `number` will be passable to an object that expects one or the other:

```
interface IConstructorReg<T extends string | number> {
    constructor: new (...args: any[]) => BaseImportObj;
    check(data: T, fileName: string): boolean;
}

const b: Array<IConstructorReg<string | number>> = [];
b.push(objImp1); 
b.push(objImp2); 
b[0].check(0, ""); // Ok
b[0].check("0", ""); // Also Ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCSBbADgewE4BcDyARgFbQDeAvgFCiQwCCAygMIBKCYAJglmVZQJYA7HNwBmYYAmhImGQRBxYArsBzY2AcwA8AFWgIAHiMEcYCrEI3QAPtEFKUBbgD4ylaB+jA55lWqwAXHYIAO7QABQAdNFgWBoQQWCCAJ4A2gC6AJTQALyu8BDI6Nj4xADc7p7AABYIwADW4RxgOGBBOgA00KL8IAgAcmAoCEHmlplBBBgYfUkVfJSiSoKq-HJetQ0AYssAjE0tbdBjghpdPX2Dw6OK426e0AD0j9AMCABu3GAgMEyb9dwYNFIpUPFgEDglFhBNBFEoEPNqD4cNAMMRUGhdkEZMjlKp1AhtCcNK4cmQvLi-NggoxWOwuFgujU6vUgsztntoOQKotlqt1uz6jtBAAmA6tIL2Rzcc69AZDEbHW6nbKkUFPF5vT5Yb6-f6A6DA9XgyHQ2HKBGUKjeeQotFEDEi7GyW14-yaLRSpxYUnkm2+fGBaC0ticGUbFls-7CkVcnn+lEEGlYHXJLQ411UrAe4k2OwOb3OX0ZCoESJoJQQarhe0Y3aZMrQShlitVmvo9AihtNgipAAM6UigvCfa6ACIx93ntA8PVm-3B8Ox32x+PJ43p3QfhgZ-UgA)