# Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, covariance, contravariance, generic-variance, invariance

Could you please explain using small and simple TypeScript examples what is Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance?

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you please revert your changes ?

Comment: No; the question part of the post is for _a question_, not just a scratchpad. If you'd like to write an additional answer (what you've posted so far would be link-only, though), do so _as an answer_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ahh, ok, you are right, but I am too lazy to copy these links. For interested persons: you can check edit history of this question and copy related links

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Variance** has to do with how a generic type `F<T>` *varies* with respect to its type parameter `T`.  If you know that `T extends U`, then variance will tell you whether you can conclude that `F<T> extends F<U>`, conclude that `F<U> extends F<T>`, or neither, or both.

---

**Covariance** means that `F<T>` and `T` *co*-*vary*. That is, `F<T>` *varies with* (in the same direction as) `T`. In other words, if `T extends U`, then `F<T> extends F<U>`.  Example:

- Function or method types co-vary with their return types:

  ```
  type Co<V> = () => V;
  function covariance<U, T extends U>(t: T, u: U, coT: Co<T>, coU: Co<U>) {
    u = t; // okay
    t = u; // error!

    coU = coT; // okay
    coT = coU; // error!
  }
  ```

Other (un-illustrated for now) examples are:

- objects are covariant in their property types, even though this not sound for mutable properties
- class constructors are covariant in their instance types

---

**Contravariance** means that `F<T>` and `T` *contra*-*vary*. That is, `F<T>` *varies counter to* (in the opposite direction from) `T`. In other words, if `T extends U`, then `F<U> extends F<T>`.  Example:

- Function types contra-vary with their parameter types (with [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled):

  ```
  type Contra<V> = (v: V) => void;
  function contravariance<U, T extends U>(t: T, u: U, contraT: Contra<T>, contraU: Contra<U>) {
    u = t; // okay
    t = u; // error!

    contraU = contraT; // error!
    contraT = contraU; // okay
  }
  ```

Other (un-illustrated for now) examples are:

- objects are contravariant in their key types
- class constructors are contravariant in their construct parameter types

---

**Invariance** means that `F<T>` neither varies with nor against `T`: `F<T>` is neither covariant nor contravariant in `T`.  This is actually what happens in the most general case.  Covariance and contravariance are "fragile" in that when you combine covariant and contravariant type functions, its easy to produce invariant results.  Example:

- Function types that return the same type as their parameter neither co-vary nor contra-vary in that type:

  ```
  type In<V> = (v: V) => V;
  function invariance<U, T extends U>(t: T, u: U, inT: In<T>, inU: In<U>) {
    u = t; // okay
    t = u; // error!

    inU = inT; // error!
    inT = inU; // error!
  }
  ```

---

**Bivariance** means that `F<T>` varies *both* with *and* against `T`: `F<T>` is both covariant nor contravariant in `T`.  In a sound type system, this essentially *never happens* for any non-trivial type function.  You can demonstrate that only a constant type function like `type F<T> = string` is truly bivariant (quick sketch: `T extends unknown` is true for all `T`, so `F<T> extends F<unknown>` and `F<unknown> extends T`, and in a sound type system if `A extends B` and `B extends A`, then `A` is the same as `B`.  So if `F<T>` = `F<unknown>` for all `T`, then `F<T>` is constant).

But Typescript does not have [nor does it intend to have](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) a fully sound type system.  And there is [one notable case](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) where TypeScript treats a type function as bivariant:

- Method types both co-vary and contra-vary with their parameter types (this also happens with all function types with `--strictFunctionTypes` disabled):

  ```
  type Bi<V> = { foo(v: V): void };
  function bivariance<U, T extends U>(t: T, u: U, biT: Bi<T>, biU: Bi<U>) {
    u = t; // okay
    t = u; // error!

    biU = biT; // okay
    biT = biU; // okay
  }
  ```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKF5AXBPAHBTABAYQPYB4BqA+RBeRACgEp9dMBuUAMwFcA7AY0gEtV7FHUA3AQwCcWvJvHQBVADSIAKongAPSPHoATAM6Ix2QpABcMqbX2TOqafrTpp2KVzEWMW0gG9Qid4lr5EkCogD0-oioANa80G4ekN60foFy-Pyo-ACEEB6mYt5c0nFBoeGR7jnZqGJ5CUmpoAC+EDAIKOyQ-LxYuASE3PqYpHi43KgsKlQgdEys7Kb0Lbx8gsKMoiayCkqqGlo6+tKGxrbNreZNM61WNtOz9iez4tguRZ7evgH5YREgGdEEsa+VyWkwJ8PFxTrwsgRQbNcn94IkAY8oUdSmDyn8Ch86kCGkgAJL0dreLo9PrkUbjZhsDgsejzIQicRSVaKZTqTTaPQGTz7RA047485SGnXAVORCuYHuLwEF7xDGPb6eCpwqqAx7C7x85Xw6qS3n0WQEYXa1W1epwJAAIRYhIIzkQ1FQqGJiF6+kGw0QNXJDEpUwARiw6Ytlky5CyNuztlyjJopIHjtbBYhA9ck2KJRlpT4KvK9YrfvEVQigRlU94E7n3o8ExWWGi5dWQFigA)

Comment: What an amazing mind-twisting exercise!

Answer (score 5):

*<sub>A.S.: [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/4554883) is great from the technical perspective. I'd like to add some intuition to it.</sub>*

## When variance is relevant?

The concept of variance becomes useful when you are dealing with two types that are neither exactly identical to each other, nor completely unrelated to each other.

Here's why.

In this example, both `value1` and `value2` are of the same type — `number`, and so [one is always assignable to the other and vice versa, without any errors](https://tsplay.dev/wOrXRW):

```
declare let value1: number // for example: 42, or -3, or NaN, etc.
declare let value2: number // for example: 17, or Math.PI, or Infinity, etc.

value1 = value2 // no error
value2 = value1 // no error
```

Conversely, here `value1` is a `number`, while `value2` is a `string`. These types are as unrelated to each other as it can possibly get, and so [assigning one to the other is always an error](https://tsplay.dev/mLrA2w):

```
declare let value1: number // for example: 42, or 17, etc.
declare let value2: string // for example: "Hello world", "Lorem ipsum", etc.

value1 = value2 // Error!
value2 = value1 // Error!
```

In both of these cases, regardless of the assignment direction (`value2` to `value1` or vice versa), the result is always the same: always no error in the first case, and always an error in the second. That's why variance isn't at play here.

### Variance becomes relevant when the assignability direction matters

When you have two types that are somewhat similar but not identical, that's when the order of assignment usually matters: assigning one value to the other is fine, but it doesn't work in reverse.

Let's see an example.

Here, the type `Person` only has one property `name`, while the type `Student` defines both `name` and `graduationYear`. That is, `Student` contains everything from `Person`, while `Person` covers `Student` only partially. [Assigning a person to a student is an error](https://tsplay.dev/NrjE1N), because a student is expected to have a graduation year, but `Person` only has `name`. However, [assigning a student to a person works just fine](https://tsplay.dev/NrjE1N), since a student, just like any person, has a name (regardless of whether it has any other properties):

```
type Person = { name: string }
type Student = { name: string, graduationYear: number }

declare let person: Person // for example: { name: 'Mike' }
declare let student: Student // for example: { name: 'Sofia', graduationYear: 2020 }

person = student // no error
student = person // Error!
```

This is not variance yet, though.

## What is variance?

Variance is a measure of how the assignability between instances of a given generic correlates with the assignability between instances of its type parameters.

…

Okay, let's unpack that.

A [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) is a type that is defined through another type. A good example of a generic is `Array`: `Array<number>` is not the same as `Array<string>`, even though both are arrays. The `number` in `Array<number>` and the `string` in `Array<string>` are type parameters (or type arguments) of a generic type `Array<…>`.

Any value can be an item of an array (even another array). Which means that `Array` does not impose any constraints on its type argument; and for any `Value`, the expression `Array<Value>` creates a perfectly valid, usable type. The question is, if I have `Array<A>` and `Array<B>`, which can be assigned to which?

That's variance.

**Given the assignability between `A` and `B`, variance specifies the assignability between `F<A>` and `F<B>`** (where `F<…>` is a generic).

---

Since assignability has [direction](https://tsplay.dev/NrjE1N), there are four possible situations:

- wrapping a type in a generic keeps the assignability direction as it is ("covariance"; the generic varies in the same direction, i.e., it *co-*varies with its type argument);
- wrapping a type in a generic reverses the direction ("contra-variance"; the generic varies in the  opposite direction, i.e., it *contra-*varies with its type argument);
- wrapping a type in a generic disallows both directions ("invariance"); and
- wrapping a type in a generic allows both directions ("bivariance").

> It may be helpful (if not slightly creepy) to compare this to [blood types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type): type **A** contains anti-B antibodies; type **B** contains anti-A antibodies; type **AB** contains no antibodies; finally, type **O** contains both antibodies.