# Typescript generics strange behavior

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

do you know why the Typescript compiler (4.3.5) works with the `mergeAll1` method but fails on `mergeAll2`?

The not expected result type `Map2<T> & Map2<Base>` is not very handy :(

```js
export type ActionReducerX<T> = () => T;

export type Map1<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key];
};

export type Map2<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: ActionReducerX<T[key]>;
};

interface Base {
  a: { aa: string };
}

type WithBase<T> = T & Base;

export function mergeAll1<T>(t: Map1<T>): Map1<WithBase<T>> {
  const b: Map1<Base> = {
    a: { aa: '' }
  };

  return {
    ...t,
    ...b
  };
}

export function mergeAll2<T>(t: Map2<T>): Map2<WithBase<T>> {
  const b: Map2<Base> = {
    a: () => ({ aa: '' })
  };

  // error TS2322: Type 'Map2<T> & Map2<Base>' is not assignable to type 'Map2<WithBase<T>>'.
  return {
    ...t,
    ...b
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is in `export type ActionReducerX<T> = () => T;`.

Seem to be that `Map2<WithBase<T>>` and `Map2<T> & Map2<Base>` are assignable to each other:

```js
declare var returnType: Map2<WithBase<Value>>
declare var returnValue: Map2<Value> & Map2<Base>

returnType = returnValue
returnValue = returnType
```

But this is not the case when we use them with function argument type.

```js
export function mergeAll2<T>(t: Map2<T>): Map2<WithBase<T>> {
    const b: Map2<Base> = {
        a: () => ({ aa: '' })
    };

    let x: Map2<T> & Map2<Base> = null as any as Map2<T> & Map2<Base>;
    let y: Map2<WithBase<T>> = null as any as Map2<WithBase<T>>

    x = y // ok
    y = x // error


    const result = {
        ...t,
        ...b
    };

    return result // error
}
```

Because function arguments are contravariant, we are no more allowed to assign `x` to `y` (`Map2<T> & Map2<Base>` to `Map2<WithBase<T>>`), [`The arrow of inheritance points in the opposite direction`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696173/strictfunctiontypes-restricts-generic-type) .

There is a workaround:

```js
export type ActionReducerX<T> = <U extends T>() => U;

export type Map2<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: ActionReducerX<T[key]>;
};

interface Base {
    a: { aa: string };
}

type WithBase<T> = T & Base;

export function mergeAll2<T>(t: Map2<T>): Map2<WithBase<T>> {
    // remove explicit type
    const b = {
        a: () => ({ aa: '' })
    };

    return {
        ...t,
        ...b
    }
}
```

We can make this function `contravariant` from the beginning.

```js
export type ActionReducerX<T> = <U extends T>() => U;

type Animal = {
    name: string
}

type Dog = {
    paws: 4
} & Animal

type Check = Animal extends Dog ? true : false // false

type Check2 = ActionReducerX<Animal> extends ActionReducerX<Dog> ? true : false // true
```

Try to remove extra `U` generic argument, and you will see that inheritance behavior will be changed in opposite direction.

**I'm open to any sort of critics since this topic (variance) is still hard for me.**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696173/strictfunctiontypes-restricts-generic-type), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH49aarW6sU) you can find more about this topic

**UPDATE** Custom wrapper for `ActionReducer`

> Sadly it is not possible for me to extend the ActionReducer

You can just create your own custom type wrapper. See `Wrapper`

```js
export type ActionReducerX<T> = () => T;

type Wrapper<T extends (...args: any) => any> = <U extends ReturnType<T>>() => U

export type Map2<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: Wrapper<ActionReducerX<T[key]>>;
};

interface Base {
    a: { aa: string };
}

type WithBase<T> = T & Base;

export function mergeAll2<T>(t: Map2<T>): Map2<WithBase<T>> {
    // remove explicit type
    const b = {
        a: () => ({ aa: '' })
    };

    return {
        ...t,
        ...b
    }
}

type Animal = {
    name: string
}

type Dog = {
    paws: 4
} & Animal

type Check = Animal extends Dog ? true : false // false

type Check2 = Wrapper<ActionReducerX<Animal>> extends Wrapper<ActionReducerX<Dog>> ? true : false // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjGBLCA7AJWABMBXDYKADQB4AVAPjgF44AKAShaboG4AofkhRwA6lACGYFFHpxQMYHmIBndgDpNEqAHMVALjgS8iLsybHETVjQCq8kIuVqiMUlDx1kwegwaduOFtBUEhYBG84AFkpACZfFjgAb344NLgAbQBrYEQ4bDw4HMQIADM4OgBdQ3EpGRpMHHwiMgpqemzcyr8BAF8BfgLFKFKJCjgAIQkVVBT0o0MkowlDFRgoAp04fv5ewWFUUWwYAAspmYTWOjgAMknp4AHQ6HhS0jwsXEKAW0odYDQABtAfFGGwYIYYmBQQwOJC4jQjqdzj5GEw5ukAPSYuBQYDfCAAN1QoUB2AwxwiKFS6Qw%20DWcAARokMfM0it2GYmGwlhIOQByfnbDg0tI7UW44BuDzJCXzTTqGAAGjl6QVjIlez2QkiaDw2G%20EkBLIleAkv1W602u32kQAIhAtqxWXAwBIAO4GOAAFl2t3Q%20sNgNtIgAwidgBgsok9QajQ4nKo4A6tgB%20BBQUioQyjQEzODYuC5mYh1DhyNZWKJWrSSgNT7NEjkSi0WNBvwJpRJmv1RpfFrN9opjvp9ZZuA5o35wtj4BAA)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Sadly it is not possible for me to extend the ActionReducer :(