# Assigning function with incompatible type to ref attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Why does the following code not cause a compile-time error?

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Test extends React.Component {
  private _onReferenceUpdated = (ref: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
    ref.width = 4; // This could throw, when ref is null
  };

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <canvas ref={this._onReferenceUpdated} />
    );
  }
}
```

The `ref` attribute is inferred as

`(JSX attribute) React.ClassAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>.ref?: string | ((instance: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => void) | React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement> | null | undefined`

which seems correct (the `string` is a bit weird, but i guess that's just generally for attributes). How is `(ref: HTMLCanvasElement) => void` assignable to `(instance: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => void`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I only researched far enough to get an outline of the problem. If there is a proper explanation in a different question, or someone with a better understanding is willing to give one, feel free to add.

---

In Typescript 2.6, the [strict function types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) setting was added, now checking function parameters contravariantly. Therefore,

```
const f = (p: HTMLCanvasElement) => void p;
const g: (p: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => void = f;
```

is an error with that setting enabled. However, sadly, due to what seems to be a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30748), there is a problem with e.g. the `ref` prop in TSX:

> there is no way to tell TypeScript that the "ref" prop actually is contravariant

What follows is the [bivarianceHack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667959/what-is-the-purpose-of-bivariancehack-in-typescript-types), or in other words, `ref` behaves as-if `strictFunctionChecks` was disabled. Then, `HTMLCanvasElement` is a subtype of `HTMLCanvasElement | null`, and accepted.

This is also visible, when following the type definition, which leads to:

```
type RefCallback<T> = { bivarianceHack(instance: T | null): void }["bivarianceHack"];
```

I find this quite sad (especially, that this hack isn't visible in the type annotation, at least not in vscode), and any proper solutions, or updates on the topic, are welcome. At the very least, i am considering an ESLint typescript rule, that just forces the parameter of any function passed to `ref` to be nullable, in a hardcoded way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is kinda right there in your question.

As you noted, the type of `ref` is inferred as:

`(JSX attribute) React.ClassAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>.ref?: string | ((instance: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => void) | React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement> | null | undefined`

This is a "union" type, meaning any of the types separated by pipes (`|`) are valid here. So `ref` can be any one of the following:

- `(JSX attribute) React.ClassAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>.ref?: string`
- `((instance: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => void)`
- `React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>`
- `null`
- `undefined`

Well, you've defined the `_onReferenceUpdated` property, which you're passing to `ref`, as follows:

```
  private _onReferenceUpdated = (ref: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
    ref.width = 4; // This could throw, when ref is null
  };
```

So the type of `_onReferenceUpdated` is `(ref: HTMLCanvasElement) => void`, which handily matches one of our valid `ref` types above: `((instance: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => void)`.

Note that the wrapping parenthesis are meaningless, they just help for readability. Also note that it does not matter that the name of the parameter is "ref" in one type and "instance" in the other. All that matters is the *order* and *type* of the function parameters, and the return type.

In TypeScript it is totally valid and fine to do something like this:

```
let Foo = (a: string) => {}; // inferred type of Foo is "(a: string) => void"

Foo = (b: string) => {}; // no error; order and type of args and return type match
Foo = (c: number) => {}; // error! type of arguments don't match
```

Comment: Thanks, but why is this valid? In one function, the parameter could potentially be `null`, while in the other, it cannot. This is also the real issue: `ref` could be `null` (when the component unmounts), and neglecting this in the function is invalid. If i do the same manually, it also gives an error: https://i.imgur.com/cF796Xt.png - which is what i would expect.